# Multivariate MC: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: monte-carlo, simulations, multivariate

I am trying to generate multivariate MC results presented in this paper *A Simple Generalisation of Kirk’s Approximation for Multi-Asset Spread Options by the Lie-Trotter Operator Splitting Method*, by Chi-Fai Lo
https://file.scirp.org/pdf/JMF_2014050615380663.pdf.

I made different attemps using different approaches but I always end up producing the same incorrect result. For example my code for generating the first element in table 5.1 produces `13.7424 +/- 0.0045` instead of `13.5763 ± 0.0089`.

Here below is the Python code I made

If someone is kind enough to tell me what I am doing wrong ....

(for info I can confirm the EK values in the paper are correct because I could find the values provided by Kirk)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

nb_simuls = 10_000_000

# parameters from https://file.scirp.org/pdf/JMF_2014050615380663.pdf Table 1 / cell 1
S1, S2, S3 = 50, 60, 150
v1, v2, v3 = 0.3, 0.3, 0.3

rho_12, rho_23, rho_13 = 0.40, 0.20, 0.80

K = 30.0
T = 0.25
r = 0.05

# from spot to forward values
F1 = S1 * np.exp(r*T)
F2 = S2 * np.exp(r*T)
F3 = S3 * np.exp(r*T)

# derive volatilities from yearly volatility
vols = np. array([v1, v2, v3]) * np.sqrt(T)

# determine covariance matrix from correls and volatilities

correl = np.asarray([[1,     rho_12,   rho_13],
                     [rho_12,    1,     rho_23],
                     [rho_13,   rho_23,   1]])

cov = np.diag(vols).dot(correl).dot(np.diag(vols))

# simulate prices
returns = 1 + np.random.default_rng().multivariate_normal((0, 0, 0), cov, nb_simuls)

# determine exercise and value
values = []
for i in range(nb_simuls):
    v = max(0, F3 * returns[i, 2] - F1 * returns[i, 0] - F2 * returns[i, 1] - K)
    values.append(v)


v, se = np.mean(values) * np.exp(-r*T), scipy.stats.sem(values) * np.exp(-r*T)
print(f"The option value is: {v} +/- {se}")
# The option value is: 13.742449851577431 +/- 0.004475778801668813
```

Comment: At a first glance, can you increase your number of simulations? They use 900,000,000.
Thought it is weird that your standard error is lower than theirs if you have less simulations.

Comment: @phdstudent I tried up to 15 M but the result did not change ... I can't go above that number of simulation because of system restrictions ....

Comment: I don't see any particular problem with your approach. Could it be that they do not account for the discount factor, in the mean and stdev estimation? For this example it could explain the discrepancy, if you have the same behaviour for other configurations, then it's probably just that

Comment: @Quantuple without considering the df the discrepencies are even bigger. Also, I know their value has to be the correct one because it is much closer the value given by kirk formula (I checked that one)

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, I applied the df to your result. Need my coffee. I had a quick look through the paper, they seem to postulate Black Scholes, i.e. $S_T = F(0,T) \exp(-1/2\sigma^2T + \sigma \sqrt{T} z)$ for one asset while you are doing $S_T = F(0,T) (1 + \sigma\sqrt{T}z)$

Comment: @Quantuple thank you this was indeed my mistake,  I put a modified version of my code below ...  for my info would it be possible to achieve the same still using the covaraince matrix instead of the correlation matrix ?

Comment: Do you mean something like $S_T = F(0,T) \times \exp( - 1/2 \text{diag}(\Sigma) + Z )$ where $F(0,T)$ is the 3x1 vector of forwards, $\times$ denotes the component by component vector multiplication, $\Sigma$ the 3x3 covariance matrix and $Z \sim N( {\bf{0}}, \Sigma )$ a sample from the multivariate normal with mean ${\bf{0}}=(0,0,0)$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$ ?

Comment: @Quantuple  yes this is what I meant but here diag(Σ) is a vector ... I tried something like the follow but it does not work ...

    Fi_exp = Fi * np.exp(-0.5 * np.diag(correl)[i] + returns[n, i])

Comment: Well yes it needs to be a 3x1 vector, like the forward price vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Quantuple comments (thank you), I fixed many mistakes and I came up with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

nb_simuls = 5_000_000

# parameters from https://file.scirp.org/pdf/JMF_2014050615380663.pdf Table 1 / cell 1
S1, S2, S3 = 50, 60, 150
v1, v2, v3 = 0.3, 0.3, 0.3

rho_12, rho_23, rho_13 = 0.40, 0.20, 0.80

K = 30.0
T = 0.25
r = 0.05

# from spot to forward values
F1 = S1 * np.exp(r*T)
F2 = S2 * np.exp(r*T)
F3 = S3 * np.exp(r*T)

# derive volatilities from yearly volatility
vols = np. array([v1, v2, v3])

# determine covariance matrix from correls and volatilities

correl = np.asarray([[1,     rho_12,   rho_13],
                     [rho_12,    1,     rho_23],
                     [rho_13,   rho_23,   1]])

# simulate prices
returns = np.random.default_rng().multivariate_normal((0, 0, 0), correl, nb_simuls)

# determine exercise and value
values = []
for i in range(nb_simuls):
    F3_exp = F3 * np.exp(-0.5 * v3 ** 2 * T + v3 * np.sqrt(T) * returns[i, 2])
    F2_exp = F2 * np.exp(-0.5 * v2 ** 2 * T + v2 * np.sqrt(T) * returns[i, 1])
    F1_exp = F1 * np.exp(-0.5 * v1 ** 2 * T + v1 * np.sqrt(T) * returns[i, 0])

    v = max(0, F3_exp - F1_exp - F2_exp - K)

    values.append(v)


v, se = np.mean(values) * np.exp(-r*T), scipy.stats.sem(values) * np.exp(-r*T)
print(f"Method 1 (using correlation matrix):   The option value is: {v} +/- {se}")
# The option value is: 13.742449851577431 +/- 0.004475778801668813




# derive volatilities from yearly volatility
vols = np. array([v1, v2, v3]) * np.sqrt(T)

# determine covariance matrix from correls and volatilities

correl = np.asarray([[1,     rho_12,   rho_13],
                     [rho_12,    1,     rho_23],
                     [rho_13,   rho_23,   1]])

cov = np.diag(vols).dot(correl).dot(np.diag(vols))

# simulate prices
returns = np.random.default_rng().multivariate_normal((0, 0, 0), cov, nb_simuls)

# determine exercise and value
values = []
for i in range(nb_simuls):
    F3_exp = F3 * np.exp(-0.5 * np.diag(cov)[2] + returns[i, 2])
    F2_exp = F2 * np.exp(-0.5 * np.diag(cov)[1] + returns[i, 1])
    F1_exp = F1 * np.exp(-0.5 * np.diag(cov)[0] + returns[i, 0])

    v = max(0, F3_exp - F1_exp - F2_exp - K)
    values.append(v)


v, se = np.mean(values) * np.exp(-r*T), scipy.stats.sem(values) * np.exp(-r*T)
print(f"Method 2 (using covariance matrix):   The option value is: {v} +/- {se}")

# Method 1 (using correlation matrix): The option value is: 13.5738 +/- 0.0066
# Method 2 (using covariance matrix):  The option value is: 13.5803 +/- 0.0066
```